# Embedded Google v8 memory leak with sample

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, visual-studio-2017, v8, embedded-v8

I'm trying to embed V8 but I have some memory leaks. The following minimal code reproduce the leaks.

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    // V8 version 7.1.302.33
    v8::V8::InitializeICUDefaultLocation(argv[0]);
    v8::V8::InitializeExternalStartupData(argv[0]);
    std::unique_ptr<v8::Platform> platform = v8::platform::NewDefaultPlatform();
    v8::V8::InitializePlatform(platform.get());
    v8::V8::Initialize();

    v8::Isolate::CreateParams create_params;
    create_params.array_buffer_allocator = v8::ArrayBuffer::Allocator::NewDefaultAllocator();

    v8::Isolate* pIsolate = v8::Isolate::New(create_params); // If I remove this line and the next one, memory leak disappears
    pIsolate->Dispose();

    v8::V8::Dispose();
    v8::V8::ShutdownPlatform();
    delete create_params.array_buffer_allocator;
}
```

With this code, my visual studio 2017 print theses leaks in the output

```
Detected memory leaks!
    Dumping objects ->
{5565} normal block at 0x000001BA6F417950, 8 bytes long.
    Data: < i    > 00 00 E8 69 18 00 00 00
{5564} normal block at 0x000001BA6F416960, 16 bytes long.
    Data : <8 >o > 38 D7 3E 6F BA 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
{5563} normal block at 0x000001BA6F3ED720, 56 bytes long.
    Data: <  >o > o > A0 D6 3E 6F BA 01 00 00 A0 D6 3E 6F BA 01 00 00
{989} normal block at 0x000001BA6F4194E0, 128 bytes long.
    Data: <  >o > o > A0 D6 3E 6F BA 01 00 00 A0 D6 3E 6F BA 01 00 00
{988} normal block at 0x000001BA6F416CD0, 16 bytes long.
    Data: < p `             > 70 B4 60 0A FF 7F 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
{987} normal block at 0x000001BA6F417270, 16 bytes long.
    Data : < X `             > 58 B4 60 0A FF 7F 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
{986} normal block at 0x000001BA6F3ED6A0, 56 bytes long.
    Data : <  >o > o > 20 D7 3E 6F BA 01 00 00 20 D7 3E 6F BA 01 00 00
    Object dump complete.
```

So do you know what I forget ?

Thanks in advance for your help ;)

Comment: The documentation for [v8::Isolate::New](https://v8docs.nodesource.com/node-0.8/d5/dda/classv8_1_1_isolate.html#af4256de5ef8bc7231fa4ebe304d750bf) doesn't show an overload accepting `create_params` but since it compiles, I guess it must exist. Are those params making the Isolate being entered by a thread? _The isolate must not be entered by any thread to be disposable._

Comment: Believe those docs a little old [this link](https://v8docs.nodesource.com/node-10.6/d5/dda/classv8_1_1_isolate.html#a22dcf3922846c4971d801e5b41fd3ba7) seem to have the correct function prototype

Comment: In fact, this code is the [V8 hello world](https://github.com/v8/v8/blob/master/samples/hello-world.cc) in minimal forme. I have the same memory leak with the full hello world code

Answer (score 0):

I copied your code, and ran it on linux environment, with -fsanitize=address flag setted, didn't get any memory leak error.

Comment: If have it only on windows OS

Answer (score 0):

Here a dirty workaround to remove most memory leaks.
You have to redefine the internal class `IsolateAllocator` to call private function `FreeProcessWidePtrComprCageForTesting()`.
A first way by adding a new function `Free()` to be able to call the private function.

```cpp
namespace v8::internal
{
class IsolateAllocator
{
public:
    static void Free() { FreeProcessWidePtrComprCageForTesting(); }
private:
    static void FreeProcessWidePtrComprCageForTesting();
};
} // namespace v8::internal
```

or without adding a function to `IsolateAllocator`, but using a friend class like it's done in v8 unit test (I just rename the friend class).

```cpp
namespace v8::internal
{
class IsolateAllocator
{
private:
    friend class SequentialUnmapperTest;
    static void FreeProcessWidePtrComprCageForTesting();
};

class SequentialUnmapperTest
{
public:
    static void Free() { IsolateAllocator::FreeProcessWidePtrComprCageForTesting(); }
};
} // namespace v8::internal
```

Call the Free() function before `v8::V8::Dispose();`:

```cpp
    isolate->Dispose();
    v8::internal::IsolateAllocator::Free();
    v8::V8::Dispose();
    v8::V8::ShutdownPlatform();
    delete create_params.array_buffer_allocator;
```

There is still few memory leak due to call `v8::V8::InitializeICUDefaultLocation()` (which do some allocation using when calling `udata_setCommonData()`) and other due to `base::LazyInstance<std::weak_ptr<CodeRange>>::type process_wide_code_range_` in `code-range.cc` which store a `std::weak_ptr<>` which is never destroyed...